# Magento Translation

Tags: magento2, csv, transaction

Can Anybody Please tell me when we should use %1 or {0} in the Magento Translation?

```
In my opinion, I think One is used for the guest and the other is used for the Login Customer.
```

Answer (score 0):

That string would not require any %1.

%1 is only used when you need to replace a dynamic string value at time of requiring the translations string.

%1 is used for strings like this,

> You added %1 to your shopping cart.,You added %1 to your shopping basket.

Where %1 is dynamically replaced with the count of items added to the cart.

Comment: And When we will use the {0}